Reactor: recursion/pagination using .expand
I am trying to call an API, that returns the records between 2 given dates. However at any given time, it would return only 20 records at a time. to fetch the next 20 records I would have to check the end date in the current response, if the end date is not empty, I can go ahead and retrieve the next 20 records.
I am new to project Reactor, but I think we can do this with .expand operator and blockLast().
basically, blockLast() blocks till the time all items are fetched but at the end when I query my response I just see the last fetched item and not all the records.
Could someone please guide me to where I am going wrong
ClientResponse clientResponse =
        getAllData(id, startDate, endDate)
                .blockLast();

...
...
private Flux<ClientResponse> getAllData(String accountId, String startDate,String endDate) {
    
    return client.getAllDataV2(id, startDate, endDate)
                            .expand(response -> {
                                String nextEndDate = response.getEndDate();
                                if (nextEndDate != null) {
                                    return getAllData(accountId, startDate, nextEndDate);
                                };
                                return Flux.empty();
                            });
}


I think it would be easier to do with just concat

First, blockLast returns only the last emitted item, and discard the rest.
If you want all elements, you must collect all signals before blocking.
The easiest solution is to use collectList(), that puts all elements in a list:
List<ClientResponse> responses = getAllData(id, startDate, endDate)
        .collectList()
        .block();

You can also use another function like collect or reduce to customize how your Flux elements are merged. Imagine you have a ClientResponse#merge(ClientResponse) method that can merge two responses in one, then you can do:
ClientResponse mergedResponse = getAllData(id, startDate, endDate)
        .reduce(ClientResponse::merge)
        .block();

Now, there seems to have another little problem with your usage of expand. You seem to "nest" calls to expand by using a recursive call to getData. You should define a getPage function that returns a single page, then use it in expand:
private Mono<ClientResponse> getPage(String accountId, String startDate,String endDate) {
    // Code that fetch the first page from startDate
}

private Flux<ClientResponse> getAllData(String accountId, String startDate,String endDate) {
    
    return client.getPage(id, startDate, endDate)
                            .expand(response -> {
                                String nextEndDate = response.getEndDate();
                                if (nextEndDate != null) {
                                    return getPage(accountId, startDate, nextEndDate);
                                };
                                return Flux.empty();
                            });
}

